# MySQL - как правильно составить запрос к БД

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, join

Есть 2 таблицы.

1 таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2 таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например, мне нужно выбрать все черные книги. В таком случае, я использую запрос:

```
SELECT book.id FROM book
  LEFT JOIN book_attr ba ON(book.id = ba.book_id) WHERE ba.value = 'Big'
  GROUP BY book.id
```

Все работает корректно. Но никак не удается понять, какой составить запрос, если, например, нужно выбрать книги с value = 'Big' и книги с value = 'Red'. При чем если у книги есть value = 'Big', но нет 'Red', то эта книга не подходит. В данных таблицах книга, которая походит под вышеописанные условия имеет book_id = 3. Пока что у меня получился такой запрос:

```
SELECT book.id FROM book
  LEFT JOIN book_attr ba ON(book.id = ba.book_id) WHERE ba.value = 'Big' OR ba.value = 'Red'
  GROUP BY book.id
```

Но он не подходит, так как в результате я получаю книги с id 1 и 3 (поскольку книга с id=1 имеет value='Big', а не подходит потому, что не имеет value='Red'). Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: А зачем вообще вторая таблица? Добавил бы в первую столбцы size и color.

Comment: @yolosora к сожалению, нужна именно такая структура как приведена в вопросе( Это атрибуты книг, их может быть много и разных

Comment: Использовать `GROUP BY` без групповых функций это первый признак что, что-то не так в запросе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Держи.

**Пояснение:** нам нужен **books.id** который находится в **book_attrs.book_id** рядом с **value 'Big'** и **value 'Red'**.

Что делаем? Нам нужно условие, чтобы id был равен id в таблице **book_attrs** рядом с **value 'Big'** а так же, чтобы он был равен id в таблице **book_attrs** рядом с **value 'Red'**.

Вот и напишем же его:

```
SELECT 
   book.id as 'Red_Big_ID' 
FROM 
   book 
WHERE 
   book.id = (
      SELECT 
         book_attr.book_id as 'fid' 
      FROM 
         book_attr 
      WHERE 
         book_attr.value = 'Big' 
      AND 
         book_attr.book_id = book.id ) 
AND 
   book.id = (
      SELECT 
         book_attr.book_id as 'sid' 
      FROM 
         book_attr 
      WHERE 
         book_attr.value = 'Red' 
      AND 
         book_attr.book_id = book.id )
```

Удачи в обучении! А также [держи отличную статью-шпаргалку по SQL](https://tproger.ru/translations/sql-recap/) ✌

Answer (score 2):

Так как в таблице `book_attr` данные неоднородные, то придется искать каждый тип отдельно.

```
SELECT 
  b.*
FROM book b
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT 
     null
   FROM book_attr ba
   WHERE ba.book_id = b.id
   AND   ba.value = 'Big')
AND EXISTS
   (SELECT
      null
    FROM book_attr ba
    WHERE ba.book_id = b.id
   AND   ba.value = 'Red')
```